# Agrupar informações com uma variável em comum em PHP + SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou desenvolvendo um código onde tenho algumas notas fiscais relacionadas para um usuário ( id único ) , e quando tira as informações me vem várias linhas com o nome do usuário e a nota fiscal correspondente , contudo gostaria que fosse agrupado .

Como está hoje :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu queria que ficasse :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu código :

```
<?php 
session_start();
            $serverName = "DB_NAME";
            $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"TABELA_NAME", "UID"=>"USUARIO", "PWD"=>"SENHA" );
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
                 if ($conn === false) {
                  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

 $query = ("SELECT * FROM PEDIDOS");
 $params = array(); 
 $options = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);

?>
    <?php include("cabecalho.php")?>

        <br>
        <!-- ##### Breadcrumb Area Start ##### -->

        <center>
            <a href="index.php" class="nav-brand"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </center>
        <br>
        <center>
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>

                        <th>
                            <center>PEDIDOS</center>
                        </th>
                        <th><a onClick="window.print()" /><i class="fas fa-print"></a></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        </table>
    </center>

                <?php while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {  ?>

    <center>
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
               <tr>

                    <th>
                        <center>ID_Usuarios</center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <center>Nota Fiscal</center>
                    </th>
<th>
                        <center>Data</center>
                    </th>
<th>
                        <center>Frete</center>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                           <td>
                            <center>
                                <?php echo $row['ID']; ?>
                            </center>
                        </td>
   <td>
                    <?php echo $row['NF']; ?>
                   </td>

                        <td>
                            <center>
                               <?php echo date('d/m/y');?>
                            </center>
                        </td>

                   <td>
                    <?php echo $row['FRETE']; ?>
                   </td>

         </tbody>
         </table>
         </center>

         <br><br><br>
                <?php } 
    ?>

    <!-- ##### Breadcrumb Area End ##### -->
    <?php include("rodape.php")?>
```

Comment: não entendi bem o problema.. você quer que quando o id não se repita? não acha mais negócio controlar isso no código?